# Wrap text to minimize width in a variable width container

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I have a set of boxes that each contain some text and an image. Each box must be between 100px and 200px. The text can be up to 2 lines and will truncate otherwise. I want to minimize the width of my box so that the text wraps if possible without truncating. In other words, the box should only be 200px wide if the text truncates or takes up the full two lines. Setting something like `width: max-content` on the text section causes the box to hit 200 px before wrapping at all. I'm very new to CSS so any help is appreciated.

Example of what I want and what it does instead
[image]

Sample code:

```
<div class="my-box">
    <div class="section-text">
        <span class="truncated-text">a very very long sentence is here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="section-image">
        <img src="https://my_cool_url.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.my-box {
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 200px;

    .section-text {
        width: auto;
        .truncated-text {
            text-align: center;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }
    }

    .section-image {
        display: flex;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've unfortunately never found a pure CSS way to do this. As far as I can tell, when wrapping text CSS will always spread out in width as much as it can before it breaks to another line. The only way I can figure out how to do something like this is using some JavaScript to experimentally probe different possible widths (like doing a binary search to find the desired width).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help. Try following example..I have added more boxes with more content also

```
<div class="my-box">
    <div class="section-text">
        <span class="truncated-text">a very very long sentence is here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="section-image">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/2x/download--v2.png">
    </div>
</div><br>
<div class="my-box">
    <div class="section-text">
        <span class="truncated-text">a very very long sentence is here a very very long sentence is here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="section-image">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/2x/download--v2.png">
    </div>
</div><br>
<div class="my-box">
    <div class="section-text">
        <span class="truncated-text">a very very long sentence is here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="section-image">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/2x/download--v2.png">
    </div>
</div>


.section-text {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 150px;
    padding: 0px 40px;
}
.my-box {
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.truncated-text {
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 39px;
}
.section-image {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
}
img {
    border: 1px solid;
    max-width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up working around it by changing the max-width based on the length of the text. It's not perfect but it looks better than having the extra long boxes all the time

```
<c:set var="isLongTitle" value="${fn:length(myText) gt 32}"/>
<div class="my-box ${isLongTitle ? 'long-box' : 'short-box'}">
    // text
    // image
</div>
```

```
.my-box {
    min-width: 100px;
}

.short-box {
    max-width: 150px;
}

.long-box {
    max-width: 200px;
}
```